# How to let Users edit a resource they create but not others when resource doesn't belong to User?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cancan

In my application using [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) I have permissions where users can view and create stores but I also want them to only be able to edit the ones they've created. Users can create as many stores as they like, which all should be editable by them. A store doesn't have users so how could I do this when theirs no `user_id` apart of the `Store` table?

CanCan:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new 
    if user.role == "default"
      can :read, Store
      can :create, Store
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a user will be able to create as many stores as they like, a store will belong to a user.

You MUST create this relationship.

So, in the `User` model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stores
end
```

And in the `Store` model.

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

And in the `ability.rb` file, just put something like:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.role == 'default'
      can :manage, Store , :user_id => user.id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Overriding the `initialize` method in a model is frowned upon. The correct way is to use an `after_initialize` callback. This is because ActiveRecord doesn't always call `initialize`.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the following to the store model:

```
has_one :created_by, :class => User
```

Then add a migration to add a created_by_id to your Store class.

You should then be able to add a CanCan::Ability:

```
can :edit, Store, :created_by => user
```

Comment: Should I use a `has_one` if many stores can be created by a `User`?

Comment: Yes, each Store has only one created_by user right?  If you want to be able to grab a user's stores, then you should put "belongs_to :created_by, :class => User".  Then you can do User.find(...).stores or Store.find(...).created_by.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with a previous poster, that you must set up a relationship between `User` and `Store`. The relationship can be one-to-many (as Kleber S. showed), or many-to-many, if a store can have multiple users.

Then, the best way to handle access control is in the controller, by using the association. For the `show`, `edit`, `update`, `destroy` methods, you'll need to find the store, given a logged in user, so do something like this:

```
class StoresController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_store, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @store.update_attributes(params[:store])
      # redirect to show
    else
      # re-render edit, now with errors
    end
  end

  # ...

  private

  def find_store
    @store = current_user.stores.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

This way, the association takes care of limiting the lookup to only those stores that are connected to the `current_user` by foreign key. This is the standard way for RESTful Rails resources to perform access control of associated resources.